# C# use SerialPort in Thread loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, arduino, serial-port

I have an issue, I want to use a serial port in a thread loop. But I can't because my thread is not static and my threadloop is static.
Do you know how ?

My code (simplified) :

```
public static void ThreadLoop()
    {
        // My code is simplified in this example...

        do
        {
            SendToArduino(coordinate, r, g, b)

        } while (Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive);
    }

    private static void SendToArduino(string coordinate, byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        currentPort.WriteLine(coordinate);
        currentPort.Write(new Byte[] {r, g, b}, 0, 4);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using a static method for an instance thread is asking for trouble, why not make it an instance method? The problem comes in if you ever want to control two or more devices...

Comment: I wanted use a static method because, my thread works all the time.
You suggest to make an instance method of what ? a SendToArduino object? I must make SendToArduino class ?

Comment: Its difficult to see the structure of your program, but I'm assuming (based on your comments) its a console app and these are methods?

Comment: Yep it's a console app.
And yes these are my methods, I have a thread which analyze my screen.
But I don't know how do you want to process.

Comment: A thread is neither "static" nor "not static". Saying your thread is "not static" makes no sense, and checking `Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive` similarly makes no sense (the only way for code to execute is in a thread, so by definition if the code executed, the thread executing that code must be alive). Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces whatever problem you are having, and provide a better problem description than simply "I can't".

Comment: In your code I can't see any non-static parts... Except the currentPort. Is this variable your "non static thread"?